# Emptying a list or dictionary for reuse

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a script that looks like this

```
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

a=[]
b=[]
c={}
d={}

def program():
    a.append(1)
    c[randint(10, 20)] = randint(0, 10) 
    do_something()
    do_something_else()

    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
    print(d)
    print('done')

    return

def do_something():
    b.append(15)
    return

def do_something_else():
    d[randint(10, 20)] = randint(0, 10)
    return


root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text="Run", command=program).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

The problem here is clicking the button runs the function `program()` again with the previous values in the lists and dictionaries and so they are just appended. I want an empty dicts and lists everytime `program()`is called.

I created a function to do just that.

```
def empty():
    global a,b,c,d
    a=[]
    b=[]
    c={}
    d={}
    return
```

Ive seen much talk about not using `global` in functions. What would be a neat way to achieve this?

Comment: As a programmer you should try very, *very*, **very** hard not to use globals.

Comment: @quamrana That's what they're asking how to do.

Comment: @Barmar: Sorry, that's my knee-jerk reaction. Its pre-programmed. Its not like its better to **try** to use globals.

Comment: The right way to do this is to create a class, and use methods to add stuff and reset the contents.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make the variables local to `program()` and pass them around:

```py
import tkinter as tk
from random import randint

def program():
    a=[]
    b=[]
    c={}
    d={}
    a.append(1)
    c[randint(10, 20)] = randint(0, 10) 
    do_something(b)
    do_something_else(d)

    print(a)
    print(b)
    print(c)
    print(d)
    print('done')


def do_something(b):
    b.append(15)


def do_something_else(d):
    d[randint(10, 20)] = randint(0, 10)


root = tk.Tk()
tk.Button(root, text="Run", command=program).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Now each call to `program()` starts with new collections.